# Jquery: Scrollable menu with images where image in the middle is bigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I really need your help. I need a menu with images you can scroll horizontal and found the scrollable plugin (http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) which do the trick.

But now I want more :) I'm showing 3 images at once and want the image in the middle to be bigger then the image to the left and right. When you e.g. scroll to the left, the middle image will get normal size and moved to the right and the image to the left will be bigger and moved to the middle. Hope you get the idea.

Can any give me a hint how to modify the plugin to my needs or do you know a different plugin who do the trick?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/ should do the trick. But it's independent from jQuery, so you wouldn't need jQuery to be loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is the only really good JS-imageflow. There are a few written in flash, but I don't knno another one for JS.

Comment: Hi Tim.
The only bad thing is that its depending on php which I dont want.

Oops I guess i deleted my previous post but thanks again

Comment: It just depends on PHP if you need the reflection. Without the reflection you can use it without PHP